# How would I make a staggered UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

How would I create a staggered UICollectionView with the code I currently have?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.collectionViewPack registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewItem" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellReuseIdentifier];
    self.collectionViewPack.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(150, 250)];
    [flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 5, 5, 5)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    [self.collectionViewPack setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    [self.collectionViewPack setAllowsSelection:YES];
    self.collectionViewPack.delegate=self;
}
```

I'd like the columns to be able to scroll independently in their respective columns, but if that's not possible then staggered would be awesome too. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the same method here as described for UITableView

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/1616513

Then in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

You just ask the cell to lay itself out and then call `systemLayoutFittingSize` on the cells `contentView` to get the calculated size.